# Android Custom Adapter Doesn't Work With RelativeLayout as root

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, custom-adapter

I created a custom adapter with an xml with root layout as linear Layout. When i tried to change the root to RelativeLayout to add a button at the right end, each time i inflate the adapter by pressing the button the app stops working
This is my xml with the relative layout that isn't working when run

```
 <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/laybackground"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="@dimen/list_item_height"
android:background="@color/tan_background"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/theImage"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"/>

<LinearLayout

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/theImage">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mokWord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    tools:text="mok"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/engWord"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    tools:text="eng"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
  </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my Adapter

```
public class WordAdapterClass extends ArrayAdapter<MokAndEngClass> {
public int col=0;
public WordAdapterClass(Activity context, @NonNull List<MokAndEngClass> objects,int backroundColor) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    col=backroundColor;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if(v==null)
    {

        LayoutInflater lv = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v=lv.inflate(R.layout.englishandmoaki,parent,false);
    }
    MokAndEngClass listItem = getItem(position);
    if(listItem!=null){
    TextView writtenInMok = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.mokWord);
    TextView writtenInEng =v.findViewById(R.id.engWord);
    ImageView realtedImage =v.findViewById(R.id.theImage);
    LinearLayout theTextLayout =(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.laybackground);
    writtenInEng.setText(listItem.getEngWord());
    writtenInMok.setText(listItem.getMokWord());
    if(listItem.putAnImage()==0)
    realtedImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
    realtedImage.setBackgroundResource(listItem.putAnImage());
    theTextLayout.setBackgroundColor(theTextLayout.getResources().getColor(col));
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: There is no button in the xml

Comment: So it worked with another layout?  Which one? Just to be certain--the name of the file with the RelativeLayout is actually "englishandmoaki"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have changed the layout type from `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` without changing the code in the `getView()` method to reflect that change--you are still trying to cast the root view to an `LinearLayout`!

Change this line of code:

```
LinearLayout theTextLayout =(LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.laybackground);
```

to

```
RelativLayout theTextLayout =(RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.laybackground);
```

and everything should work as before.

---

---

**Please Note:**
When you post a question in the future on SO and you are reporting an issue, please make it clear that "isn't working" actually means "getting an error" and you should post the stack trace from the logcat. This issue would have been clear-up in 10 seconds by the SO community.